# How can I correctly identify holes in the Cave Exploration minigames?

Tags: ducktales-the-quest-for-gold

In the DOS game Ducktales: The Quest for Gold, Cave Exploration is one of the minigames played to earn money on your quest to victory. The goal is to navigate a cave/maze while avoiding holes, a moving mummy (which follows a kind of shortest path algorithm) and do it before your torch runs out (unsure if this event is based on total time or idle time).

However the cave logic seems a bit sketchy. By first impression it should be possible to identify holes based on the slimy sections of the cave (similar logic to Wumpus-style games). However this is not always true and there exists maps which has tiles which are both slimy and contains a hole.

I'm quite frustrated that this minigame appears to be guesswork and nothing more. Can anyone explain how to correctly identify holes and stake out a winnning path in the Cave Exploration minigames?

Answer (score -1):

The green slime should mean there is a hole near. But I do not know the exact rules.